# Meaning of "I knew going into this that"?

Tags: word-usage

What does it mean when you say "I knew going into this that ~"?

For example:

> "I knew going into this that we didn't have much time."

I can figure out the meaning but can't really catch the subtle differences between "know going into this" and just "know this".

Answer (score 1):

> *I knew **(as we were)** going into this that we didn't have much time.*

You are stating that you already had knowledge, when you began this endeavor, that there was limited time to complete it.

This can be understood to mean: *I knew **as we began this endeavor** that we didn't have much time.*

You can also rephrase as: *I knew that we didn't have much time **(as we were)** going into this.*

Comment: Yeah, it's just a way of changing "I knew we didn't have much time" to say that they were aware of that before they started. They understood the situation before they began or took on the task. *Going into X* means starting something that involves some commitment